# Term for asking a question to create context

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, conversation

Sometimes to start a conversation or to bring up a subject I ask a question. I ask it in hopes that they know the answer, I'm not seeking knowledge or an explanation, but instead I'm looking to create a context for the conversation.

An example question might be something as simple as "Remember yesterday when we talked about [something we talked about yesterday]?" Obviously I don't expect them to just say "yes, I remember" and that's that. I'm bringing that conversation into mind as the context for this conversation. I imagine it's a question and not a command or a statement because 1) they may not actually remember the the conversation from yesterday and 2) courtesy.

Is there a name or phrase for this kind of question?

Comment: You might call it a *prompt*.

Comment: It's a rhetorical question (according to the more general definition _The rhetorical question is usually defined as any question asked for a purpose other than to obtain the information the question asks._ at http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/r/rhetorical%20questions.htm , but not the narrower definition at say Wikipedia). It's also a pragmatic marker, subclass 'relationships between speaker and hearer', intersecting subclass 'framing subject matter of utterances and relationships among (parts of) utterances' (though Jim's answer works too).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, roughly that sounds about right. I had expected a more specific term to exist, like those in the Related Figures where the rhetorical questions had purposes. Maybe it's a lexical gap, I don't know for sure that a specific word/phrase for this exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can call it a

[***lead in***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lead-in) : something that leads in or introduces; an introduction to a subject

Answer (score 2):

Initially I thought about the expression, *breaking the ice*; although it's usually used in those embarrassing situations where nobody knows anybody and a deathly silence ensues, a friendly question as an opener can certainly be used as a pretext for a conversation or exchange of information.

It's secondary meaning as defined by The Free Dictionary is:

> [**Break the ice**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/break+the+ice) *idiom*
>   2. *Fig*. to initiate social interchanges and conversation; to get something started.
>   *It's hard to break the ice at formal events*.

> **[Opener](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/opener)** *n.*
>   A remark used as an excuse to initiate a conversation:
>   *My store of conversational openers seems thoroughly inadequate to the task.
>
>   Sitting down beside him, Brenna wracked her brain for a conversation opener.*

> **[Conversation opener](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversation_opener)**
>   A conversation opener is an introduction used to begin a conversation. They are frequently the subject of guides and seminars on how to make friends and/or meet people. Different situations may call for different openers [...]
>
> **An opener** often takes the form of an *open-ended question*, which can lead to further comments or conversation as well as creating topics for future conversations (e.g. "*How's your mandrill doing?*").
>
> **A closed-ended question** (e.g. "*Nice weather today, isn't it?*") is regarded as potentially less effective because it can be answered with a simple "Mm-hmm," which is essentially a conversational dead end, requiring the initiater of the conversation to start from scratch.

Consequently, according to Wikipedia, the question *"Remember yesterday when we talked about [X]?"* would be termed as *a close-ended question*. As the OP rightly observed when speaking with friends a simple "yes" or "no" response is not expected, but a question is just one of many informal "tactics" that people employ everyday in order to introduce a topic or start a conversation.